# Set indent mode for tpl files in vim

Tags: vim, templates, indentation

I currently work on a cms with `.tpl` files.
It's mainly HTML so I would lile vim to understand that I want to use an "HTML complient" mode for autoindent.

When I type text, it works, but when I try `gg=G`, vim remove all tabs and spaces befor each line instead of making a clen indentation for my file.

I suppose there is something to put in my .vimrc but I don't know what.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The indent files are located in the `indent`folder where you have your vimfiles. On my machine (Windows) this is `c:\Program Files\Vim\Vim73\indent`.

You can try to copy `html.vim` to `tpl.vim`or maybe find some online to put there.

Disclaimer: I have not tries this my self.

Comment: I downloaded http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2075 and copy the vim file to ftplugin/tpl/tpl.vim but while I have no errors, `gg=G` still remove leading spaces and tabs.

Comment: According to the install instructions you should copy to the `indent`folder - `Unix: copy script to ~/.vim/indent
Win: copy script to ~\vimfiles\indent`

Comment: I currently use `pathogen` (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332) So, I moved the script to `C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\bundle\autoindents\indent\`. I duplicated html.vim to tpl.vim But as it works in HTML files, there is nothing more in TPL files.